# Active Record - How to get all Direct and Indirect children in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have a top level class for Topics, and each can have sub-topics through a parent_id

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Topic"
has_many :sub_topics, :class_name => "Topic", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

Each topic has channels...

```
has_many :channels
```

But this only gets the direct children.... and I've been struggling with a neat way to get all the channels that are decedents of a topic... including level 2, 3, 4, etc.....

```
has_many :sub_channels, :through => :sub_topics, source: :channels
```

This gets the second level channels, but ignores the top level and deeper levels... but this seems to be going down the wrong road for what I'm trying to attain...

Is there a good web resource that explains how to do this?

Comment: Checkout acts_as_nested_set for thoughts about doing this in one query.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you've got the model referencing itself and are then trying to do queries based on that. You'll need to be careful that you don't have any loops. For example if Topic A belongs_to topic B belongs_to Topic A. This becomes a problem if you're wanting to get arbitrarily deep levels of channels.

Comment: Using Postgres,

I checked out a few of the nested_set style gems... and decided to go with ancestry... Though still needing to go through the gem code in deeper detail to get a proper understanding of how it all works under the hood... though seems pretty intuitive from the top level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have spent quite a bit of time looking into this... seems the best way to go is to use one of the gems like nested set / ancestry to save having to build a lot of queries yourself. Thanks to the commenters above for the reco.